# How to post a form with javascript with the values

Tags: javascript, forms, timer

i made this little program but the values are not sent if i wait 5 seconds. When i answer within 5 seconds and press the submit button it works fine. Should i learn AJAX and JSON for making applications like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F76B4C;
}
</style>
<body>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

$achternaam = $_POST['lname'];
echo "De winnaar is: " .$achternaam;}
?>
<p>Vul snel iets in!</p>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="post">
 Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 100;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
  function frame() {
    if (width <= 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
      document.forms["myForm"].submit();
    } else {
      width--;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }
}
move()

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your suggested answer.

Comment: First, HTML5 requires you include a non-empty `action` in your form (use `action="post"` in this case). Second, you don't need AJAX or JSON to power this, although you should learn them anyways - it's a useful skill to have. Third, move your PHP down to the body or it won't appear. Although these aren't directly related to your question, I thought I'd point those out anyways.

Comment: Thank you i made de changes.

Comment: You really don't need Ajax and Json for this you can do this simply by creating a boolean value and making it false after 5 seconds and if the value is true the form is submitted else it won't be submitted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  It works if you use the onclick() javascript in the form. Use the same function in the move() function.